# Dynamically generated onclick not handled by IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, onclick, mootools

I have the following case: I want to create an object dynamically with javascript, which has an onclick function. I insert this element somewhere in my HTML, in hopes that the onclick function will be caught.

```js
var newElement= new Element('li', { 'id' : 'Foo', 'onclick' : 'Bar();'} )
$("randomElement").grab(newElement, 'top');
```

I have tested this and it works correctly in: firefox, opera, chrome, internet explorer 8 and up. My problem lies with internet explorer 7, it does not handle the event at all.
Although there is the option of dropping my support for IE7, I would still prefer to support as many browsers as possible.
Is there a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do some sort of `eval` by assigning the 'Bar()' string to the `onclick` attribute, instead of actually adding an event. If you want to directly pass an event you have to do it camelCase, so it should be `onClick` instead of `onclick`. **careful**, if you just do that change it will not work, explanation as follows:

Can you try rewriting your element creation with the following?

```
var newElement = new Element('li', { 
    id: 'Foo', 
    events: {
        click: function() { Bar(); }
    }
})
```

This is actually the preferred way of instantiating elements with events in MooTools, and avoids the implicit eval by explicitly calling the `Bar` function as part of the click callback.

Comment: `click: function { Bar(); }` ? `click: Bar` would be better…

Comment: not if `Bar` is not yet defined where you are declaring `newElement`. I purposely enclosed it in an anonymous function so that this 5 lines of code could be anywhere on his application, only requiring that at the time of clicking the element `Bar` exists on its scope.